# Should I pool db connections or create new connection per cluster?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've have an Node.js app running on multiple processes and I'm wondering if I should pool my MongoDB (using mongoose) connections our should create a new connection for each cluster fork.

Here's an example:

should I create a new DB connection for each fork like this:

```
if (cluster.isMaster) {
  var totalCPUs = os.cpus().length;
  var forks = 0;
  while (forks < totalCPUs) {
    cluster.fork();
    forks++;
  }
  cluster.on('exit', function(worker) {
    console.error("Cluster worker " + worker.id + " exited unexpectedly.");
    return cluster.fork();
  });
} else {
  mongoose.connect(uri);
  ...
  app = express()   
  http.createServer(app).listen(8080)
}
```

or create a single connection with [poolSize](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#connection_pools)

```
if (cluster.isMaster) {

  var totalCPUs = os.cpus().length;
  mongoose.connect(uri, { server: { poolSize: totalCPUs });

  var forks = 0;
  while (forks < totalCPUs) {
    cluster.fork();
    forks++;
  }
  cluster.on('exit', function(worker) {
    console.error("Cluster worker " + worker.id + " exited unexpectedly.");
    return cluster.fork();
  });
}else{
  app = express()   
  http.createServer(app).listen(8080)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code isn't sharing a common pool in the second case, you're just separately creating pools for the master and each worker process.  There isn't a way to share a single pool of MongoDB client connections across your cluster.

So assuming you're not actually using mongoose in the master process, it's better to only call `mongoose.connect` in the worker processes like you are in the first case, with the pool sized however you want it for each process.

Also note that `poolSize` defaults to 5, so even if you don't include the `poolSize` option, `mongoose.connect` is still creating a pool of connections.

Comment: I was messing around with it today and this is the same conclusion I came to. Thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: its not totally right you could maybe run 1 mongosse process and exchange the data inside the cluster. It depends much on the Scale you run this at. But at Bigger Scale of Any application you will end up in query servers that will be servers with connection pools :)